# having trouble getting all days of a duplicate week number

Tags: php, date

I'm doing a scheduling function for my project im having problem getting all the days of a given week of a given month if the last week number of the previous month is also the first week number for the next month like 5th week for Oct 2015 is 44 but Nov 2015 1st week number is also 44

Comment: the leading zero `09` is treated as an octal. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the days of the week, and test whether they're in the month you care about.

```
$month = 11;
$weekstart = strtoTime("2015W44");
$days = array();
for ($d = 0; $d < 7; $d++) {
    $day = strtotime("+$d day", $weekstart);
    if (date('n', $day) == $month) {
        $days[] = $day;
    }
}
```

When this is done, `$days` will contain timestamps for all the days in week 44 that are in November.

Comment: quoting it will produce the same result `$month = "09";` valid.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That does seem to work, but I'm not sure why. When it tests `date('n', $timestamp) == $month`, that should fail because `date` returns `9` while `$month` contains `09`, and it's doing string comparison.

Comment: Weird, `var_dump("9" == "09");` says it's true.

Comment: There was a question not long ago about zeros in a string, which turned into a rather long discussion. I should've bookmarked it. What I remember was that it was the trailing zero that produced different results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how can it be a duplicate? my problem very different than what you said is a duplicate. I actually manage to get the right week and timestamp

Comment: @SheenaSalazar if it isn't a duplicate, then Barmar's answer would be wrong then. That's what you're saying, in so many words.

Comment: @SheenaSalazar When I tried running your original code, I got no output at all. When I removed the `0`, it printed 36, 37, 37, 39, 40, with no duplicates.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're talking about October and November in the question. Month 9 is September.

Comment: my problem is when i choose week 1 for october the week im getting is week 40 so when i echo strtotime('2015W40'); the timstamp im getting is for Sept 28, 2015, when what i want to get the timestamp of monday for Oct 2015 week 1

Comment: $month = 09; is just a sample of the month i'm having trouble with

Comment: `strtotime` of a week number returns the first day of the week. If a week crosses a month boundary, it will return the first month.

Comment: That `strtotime()` is totally unrelated to the code in the question. How could I possibly have known that this was what you were having trouble with?

Comment: @Barmar for the month of Sept the result would be week = 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 which right but when you do it again for the month of october that is when i get the trouble because the first week for october is also 40 thus im having problem getting the days of the week 1 for october

Comment: Get all the days in the week. Test whether they in the month you care about, and skip the ones that aren't.

Comment: @Barmar how can i do that? really have no idea how to do it

Comment: Please edit the question to show the real problem. Then we'll reopen it and try to answer you.

Comment: @barmar thnx this is what i'm looking for. by the way sorry for the misleading question.